# Dynamic height of UITableVIewCell with different layout for selected state

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I'm trying to build a `UITableViewCell` with multiline title and subtitle. There is also a `UIButton` on the left which appears only in selected state.

Depending on the case height of the cell should be either:

- Height of title & subtitle + padding
- Height of the button + padding

[image: Cell States]

Constrains are:

- Button is pinned to the left-top corner (fixed space, 1000 priority)
- Button has fixed size (1000 priority)
- Button is pinned to the bottom of container (more or equal, 999 priority)
- Titles pinned to the button on the left, to the container on the right, have fixed vertical space between them (fixed space, 1000 priority)
- Title pinned to the top of container (fixed space, 1000 priority)
- Subtitle pinned to the bottom of container (more or equal, 1000 priority)
- Both labels have vertical content compression & hugging priorities set to 1000

The app targets iOS 8.0+, so we're using dynamic height. From `TableViewController`:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 60
```

Here is my `setSelected` method of my custom cell:

```
override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    plusButton.hidden = !selected

    let buttonAlpha: CGFloat = selected ? 1.0 : 0.0
    plusButtonWidthConstraint.constant = selected ? 38.0 : 0.0
    titleLeadingConstraint.constant = selected ? 8 : 0.0


    if animated == true {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.plusButton.alpha = buttonAlpha
            }, completion: nil)
    }
    else {
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.plusButton.alpha = buttonAlpha
    }
}
```

**The problem:** When Title and/or subtitle are long enough (so in selected mode they are higher than button) - cell height isn't stretched to the highest to the labels (see drawing 3c). 
If I select another cell - the first one redraws itself and all sizes are correct.
It seems for me that recalculation of the title's and subtitle's frames happens after cell bounds were recalculated.

**Secondary problem:** `animated` argument is always false (even if user taps on the cell. That is however doesn't make any difference for the main problem.

Comment: Is the cell only resizing itself correctly after you tap on another cell?  I'm just wondering if you need to call `cell.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()` manually, not just on the selected cell (of course, that's only if I understand the problem correctly).

Comment: You're actually right. It seems like even going back & forth in navigation stack doesn't help, but selection another sell (when problem cell is on screen) soles the problem. If I select another cell when the problem one is off screen - it doesn't solve the problem. What do you think can be a solution?

Comment: Try adding `cell.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()` after you set your constraints or in `didLayoutSubViews`.  See if that helps before we go any deeper.